# How to enable GPIO interrupt on STM32F4DISCOVERY user button from STM32CubeMX

Tags: interrupt, stm32, interrupt-handling, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I would like to enable a GPIO interrupt whenever a user presses the user button on the [STM32F4DISCOVERY](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32f4discovery.html) board.

Steps I am following:

1. Download and install STM32CubeMX 4.27.0
2. New Project
3. Board Selector
4. STM32F4DISCOVERY
5. Initialize all peripherals to their default Mode: Yes

Note that `PA0 -> B1 [Blue Push Button]`.

[image]

My understanding is that [`PA0` should be mapped to `EXTI0` interrupt](https://embeddedsystemengineering.blogspot.com/2015/08/stm32f4-discovery-tutorial-8-external.html).

6. Configuration | GPIO confirms that `PA0` is set to External Event Mode with Rising edge trigger detection

[image]

7. Configuration | NVIC

But I don't see a way to enable `EXTI0` interrupt:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on PA0 and select `Reset_State`, then select `GPIO_EXTI0`. After that, under GPIO configuration select "External Interrupt Mode ...".

Now **EXTI line0 interrupt** should be visible under NVIC configuration.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is it a bug in STM32CubeMX that when taking the defaults for the STM32F4DISCOVERY, when hovering over `PA0` it _says_ that it is configured for `GPIO_EXTI0`? I'm confused why we have to reset it, and then put it back to what it appears to already be set to initially?

Comment: Possibly a bug, also you have to select "External Interrupt Mode..." and not "External Event Mode..." as [events do not generate interrupts](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/114927/56348).